# How to change parent permalink?

Tags: theme-development, slug

I have a theme with hardcoded permalink structure for some posts. Those posts open with

```
site.com/parent/page
```

structure.

I created a filter that replaces the link from "site.com/**parent**/page" to "site.com/**newparent**/page" in functions.php with:

```
add_action('init', 'change_slug_of_post_type_parent', 20);
function change_slug_of_post_type_parent()
{   
$args = get_post_type_object("parent");
$args->rewrite["slug"] = "newparent";
register_post_type($args->name, $args);
}
```

Links are now generated OK, but when I click on them, the page doesn't load.

Can someone please help? I am sure this is easy fix, but I cant get around it.
I am new to wordpress programming (I used GSCMS, and CMSGS before).

Thanks

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules ?

Comment: Is /parent a page with the slug `parent`?

Comment: Benoti - thank you, I feel like an idiot. It worked instantly after flushing. Will you please make an answer, so I can award solution point? Thanks! .-)

Comment: Tom J Nowell  - No, the page is not parent, it is just a category pointer.

Answer (score 0):

**Benoti** posted the solution in comments: "Did you flush rewrite rules?"

How to flush: https://www.webhostinghero.com/3-ways-to-flush-the-rewrite-cache-in-wordpress/